# Helm default namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am working on a task. I ran this command
"helm install local-secret external-secrets/kubernetes-external-secrets" and after it was created it installed the helm chart into the default namespace and I need to create a namespace and change the namespace that the secret is installed in

Answer (score 1):

In order to create the resource(s) in non-default namespace, you need to specify that namespace within your install command with `-n`|`--namespace`  [flag](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_install/#options-inherited-from-parent-commands). If such namespace doesn't exist, you can also include the `--create-namespace` [flag](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_install/#options) to create it.